# Match Word before Matching Pattern Indefinite Times

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, regex-group

Examples of possible input:

```
'Starts in 09h 52m 56s'
'Ends in 00h 33m 13s'
```

The output for each of the two inputs above would be:

```
['Starts', '09', '52', '56']
['Ends', '00', '33', '13']
```

Right below is a pattern that kind of works:

```
(Starts|Ends) in ([0-9]{2})h ([0-9]{2})m ([0-9]{2})s
```

Unfortunately it outputs everything like so:

```
[('Ends', '00', '46', '34')]
```

Instead of:

```
['Ends', '00', '46', '34']
```

More importantly, however, I would like to make the regular expression more concise, instead of having to repeat `([0-9]{2})` three times.

I have tried using `(Starts|Ends)|([0-9]{2})[h|m|s]`, but this outputs the following:

```
[('Ends', ''), ('', '04'), ('', '20'), ('', '41')]
```

Again, the output that I'm looking for is simply:

```
['Ends', '00', '33', '13']
```

As was requested, here is my code:

```
regex_time_left = re.compile(r'(Starts|Ends) in ([0-9]{2})h ([0-9]{2})m ([0-9]{2})s')
for product_page in indi_product_urls:
    time_left = ff.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, 'span[id*=deal_expiry_timer_]')
    if len(time_left) > 0:
        time_left = regex_time_left.findall(time_left[0].text) # [('Ends', '00', '32', '31')]
        starts_ends = time_left[0][0]
        hours = time_left[0][1]
        minutes = time_left[0][2]
        seconds = time_left[0][3]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What's the problem with your current solution? You can just access the tuple at element 0 and convert it to a list, if that's the format you need. Can you show a case where it doesn't do what you need it to?

Comment: @pdowling ive just edited my question. its not the end of the world the way ive made it, but id like something more concise and to be able to access the output in a more simple manner

Comment: Show us your code and how the input is stored.

Comment: @yoonghm i'm scraping the input off of the web. ive added my code as u requested

Comment: Use `re'(starts|ends) in (\d{2})h (\d{2})m (\d){2})s'`. As you need to capture  the value,  you need to repeat the capture group. Unless you perform another match after ensuring the line starts with `starts in` or `ends in`.

Comment: @yoonghm your solution is no different than mine except you use `\d` instead of `[0-9]` which are pretty much the same thing...

Comment: i used `[0-9]` over `\d` for a reason: "\d
For Unicode (str) patterns:
Matches any Unicode decimal digit (that is, any character in Unicode character category [Nd]). This includes [0-9], and also many other digit characters. If the ASCII flag is used only [0-9] is matched.
For 8-bit (bytes) patterns:
Matches any decimal digit; this is equivalent to [0-9]."

Comment: Are the only strings the input will ever be ? You just need to dissect  those two lines into that format

Comment: @vash_the_stampede the format is always the same. the only things that can change are `Starts` or `Ends` (but this will always be one or the other) and the digits (`00`) for hours, minutes, and seconds

Answer (score 1):

Try this code !

You can use the `regex` (import re library in python) & extract the hours, minutes & seconds value.
Here d{2} represents the integer value with 2-digit because hours/minutes/second values are always in 2-digit.

**Code :**

```
import re

start = 'Starts in 09h 52m 56s'
end = 'Ends in 00h 33m 13s'

matchObj = re.match( r'(?:Starts|Ends)[ ]in[ ](\d{2})h[ ](\d{2})m[ ](\d{2})s', start, re.M|re.I)
print ("Start Hours : ", matchObj.group(1))
print ("Start Minutes : ", matchObj.group(2))
print ("Start Seconds : ", matchObj.group(3))


matchObj = re.match( r'(?:Starts|Ends)[ ]in[ ](\d{2})h[ ](\d{2})m[ ](\d{2})s', end, re.M|re.I)
print ("End Hours : ", matchObj.group(1))
print ("End Minutes : ", matchObj.group(2))
print ("End Seconds : ", matchObj.group(3))
```

**Output :**

```
Start Hours :  09                                                                                                                
Start Minutes :  52                                                                                                              
Start Seconds :  56                                                                                                              
End Hours :  00                                                                                                                  
End Minutes :  33                                                                                                                
End Seconds :  13
```

**Verify through regex101 :**

[image]

Comment: i need to capture `(Starts|Ends)` because i'll be using this to determine how to display the information and how to store it in the database

Comment: @Anthony okay . so you need to remove the `?:` from the start of the regex & now you can get this value on `matchObj.group(1)` , hour value at `matchObj.group(2)` , min value at `matchObj.group(3)` and seconds value at `matchObj.group(4)`. so kindly modify these changes & you will get the desire result successfully.

Comment: ya i know! what exactly does the 3rd par (`re.M|re.I`) in `re.match` do?

Comment: @Anthony `(re.M|re.I)` is a flag to control the meaning of the regular expression. It is short for re.MULTILINE and re.I is short for re.IGNORECASE.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to match words before a matching pattern indefinite times:

```
a=['starts in 09h 05m 33s','ends in 00h 33m 12s']

import re

r1 = re.compile(r'(starts|ends)')
r2 = re.compile(r'(\d{2})[hms]')

for s in a:
    m1 = r1.match(s)
    if m1:
        m2 = r2.findall(s)
        print(m1.group(0), m2[0], m2[1], m2[2])
```

Comment: as soon as i get some time ill try this!

Answer (score 0):

You can zip corresponding pairs and extra the data from the tuples

```
s = 'Start in 09h 52m 56s'
s2 = 'Ends in 00h 33m 13s'

lista = list(zip(s.split(), s2.split()))
s_list = [lista[0][0]]
e_list = [lista[0][1]]
for i in lista[2:5]:
    s_list.append(i[0][:2])
    e_list.append(i[1][:2])

print(s_list)
print(e_list)
```

> ```
> ['Start', '09', '52', '56']
> ['Ends', '00', '33', '13']
> ```

If you are doing match to the numbers I would append them as `int`s and have that done while your doing this

```
for i in lista[2:5]:
    s_list.append(int((i[0][:2])))
    e_list.append(int((i[1][:2])))
```

> ```
> ~/python/stackoverflow/9.22$ python3.7 class.py 
> ['Start', 9, 52, 56]
> ['Ends', 0, 33, 13]
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do like this,but unfortunately,using `(starts|ends)` can not suit for more situation

```
import re
a = ['starts in 09h 05m 33s','ends in 00h 33m 12s','Ends in 00h 33m 12s']
print([re.findall("(starts|ends|\d+)",i)  for i in a])
```

But you can try:

```
print([ [i.split(" ")[0]] + re.findall("\d+",i)  for i in a])
```